# Understanding a simple post-hoc power analysis of effect size

Tags: statistical-power, epidemiology, reproducible-research, social-science

I am trying to understand a relatively straightforward paragraph found in "[Gun Shows and Gun Violence: Fatally Flawed Study Yields Misleading Results](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2936974/)" by Wintermute et al that appeared in the *American Journal of Public Health*. The paragraph is as follows:

> This means the study is attempting to identify a 1.5% increase in homicides (5% × 30%). Let us also assume that the control group size is 900 000 (the maximum control group size for California), and the size of the intervention group (gun show counties) is 20 000. Using findings from Duggan et al. of a mean gun homicide rate per county of 0.035 deaths per 100 000 persons per week with a standard deviation of 0.203, then for a 2-sample test, 1-tailed, with an α of 5%, the power is 10%.

However, I am completely stymied as to how to reverse-engineer the result of "...the power is 10%". I am not at all challenging the findings of Wintermute et al. (I agree with the study). I am interested in seeing how the authors carried out this post-hoc power calculation to evaluate the effect size.

Key aspects of problem:

Control group N: 900,000

Intervention group N: 20,000

$\mu_1$: 0.035

$\sigma_1$: 0.203

$\alpha$ error rate: 0.05

2-sample test, 1-tailed direction

Could anyone provide direction from here as to next steps?

Comment: You are missing a key value: the duration of the study.  I believe the NIST assumes four weeks: "assume that (1) 5% of homicides committed with guns purchased at gun shows occur within 4 weeks and 25 miles of those shows." The crucial role of this parameter is revealed in the conclusion: "the fact that the they did not find an effect of gun shows on homicide cannot be taken to mean that no such effect exists. As we have suggested, that effect may simply be exerted over a longer time period and broader geographic area."

Comment: @whuber that is a great point! Indeed it is an important parameter. However, I'm not sure how it factors into a post-hoc power calculation?

Comment: The longer the duration, the greater the difference in (hypothetical) numbers of homicides, whence the greater the power is to detect it.

Comment: @whuber absolutely, point taken! As I mentioned in the post, in agreement with the conclusions of the AJPH rebuttal. I'm more interested in understanding how the authors got to "...the power is 10%" mathematically.

Comment: Reading the [Russ Lenth](https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Erlenth/Power/) article to improve my understanding...

Comment: Frankly, I can't even see how they obtain 10%.  Think about it: with a base homicide rate of just 0.035 per 100K per week, the expected number for 20K people over 4 weeks is 0.2*4*0.035=0.028.  That means you are unlikely to see even one homicide.  A 1.5% increase in that rate takes it all the way up to 0.029: you still won't see one homicide; and if you do, it should be interpreted as a chance occurrence. We don't need an extensive power analysis to see the problems here.

Comment: @whuber okay, fair enough. Was just caught up on the power calculations. Thanks for the comments!